# angular2 - Forms - Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined

Tags: angular

When Creating my first form in Angular2, I get this following Error:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined
>   ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot set
>   property 'stack' of undefined

I am using anguilar-cli 1.0.0-beta.25.5.
**
here is my code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template:
    `<div class="container">
           <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="submitHandler()">
             <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"       formControlName="username"
  placeholder="username...">
            </div>
          </form>
     </div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  private userForm : FormGroup;

  constructor(){
    this.userForm = new FormGroup({
      username : new FormControl(),
      password : new FormControl(),
      email : new FormControl(),
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with this piece of code, syntax-wise. Either the error is elsewhere or has something to do with angular-cli.

Comment: Did you import the ReactiveFormsModule in your AppModule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update zone.js to 0.7.6 and you'll see actual error.

Comment: That acually did the work! Now I can see that my error was "Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'" - I was missing the ReactiveFormsModule" import in my app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

It might be related to the issue here. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3975  . Do backup and try to update to the latest version.